# Displaying HTML lists with more than 10 items in columns

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a generated HTML document that contains a number of unordered lists.  Most are fairly short (eg, up to 5 entries) and some of those use full paragraphs as list entries.  However, there are a couple lists that are longer than 20 entries, all of which are very short.  I would like to display the long lists two columns but leave the short ones as single columns.

For example, I would like the list

- Something short.
- This is a long, overly verbose sentence that may wrap around on narrow screens, and certainly will wrap (perhaps more than once) if forced into two columns.
- This is some more text

to display as a single column (as it does here), but for the list

- Alice
- Bob
- Carol
- David
- Eve
- Frank
- Greta
- Howard
- Irma
- Joseph
- Katherine
- Leo
- ...

to be displayed as two columns.

Unfortunately, I can't change the tool that generates the HTML and I would rather not add a post-processing step.  However, I can change the CSS that the HTML loads.  Is there any way to achieve this using pure CSS?

I don't really care if the columnized list reads left to right then top to bottom, or top to bottom then left to right.

I've tried using `columns` (and its browser-specific variants), but haven't found any method that doesn't also force the short lists into columns.  `:nth-child` might help, but I haven't figured out how.

**EDIT**

Some of the generated HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>Composite:Aperture</li>
<li>Composite:DigitalZoom</li>
<li>Composite:DriveMode</li>
<li>Composite:FlashType</li>
<li>Composite:FOV</li>
<li>Composite:FocalLength35efl</li>
<li>Composite:HyperfocalDistance</li>
<li>Composite:ImageSize</li>
...
</ul>
```

It's just a basic, undecorated list.

Comment: Can you show an example of the generated HTML?

Answer (score 0):

How about using CSS3's for creating columns and JQuery for checking how long the text is.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NicotineLL/y57dv/1/)

CSS

```
.two-col {
    -webkit-column-count:2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
    column-count:2;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( 'li' ).each(function() { // check each li on the page (or set a class only to the li's you want to check)
        var textLength = $(this).text().length; // use text so HTML elements are not accounted for
        if(textLength >= '200'){ // change 200 to the number of characters required before applying class
            $(this).addClass('two-col'); // class name to be added
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That would require post-processing to add scripts to the file.  Not to mention that linking a big third-party library for a minor effect like this seems like overkill.  If I go with a solution that requires post-processing, I may as well just split it into two lists.

Comment: If you knew which element is "too long" you could use nth-child(n), however if there's no way of specifying which is that element by counting characters there's no way of taking action. CSS does not include such features. If the above is such a problem, I believe that you can achieve the same effect with pure JavaScript eliminating the need of JQuery inclusion. Sadly my JS knowledge is limited and I can't tell you how to do this, but you can Google it.